# Jenkins scripted Pipeline: How to apply @NonCPS annotation in this specific case

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, nio, pipeline

I am working on a scripted Jenkins-Pipeline that needs to write a String with a certain encoding to a file as in the following example:

```
class Logger implements Closeable {

    private final PrintWriter writer

    [...]

    Logger() {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true)
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw)
        this.writer = new PrintWriter(bw)
    }

    def log(String msg) {
        try {
            writer.println(msg)
            [...]
        } catch (e) {
            [...]
        }
    }
}
```

The above code doesn't work since `PrintWriter` ist not serializable so I know I got to prevent some of the code from being CPS-transformed. I don't have an idea on how to do so, though, since as far as I know the `@NonCPS` annotation can only be applied to methods.
I know that one solution would be to move all output-related code to `log(msg)` and annotate the method but this way I would have to create a new writer every time the method gets called.

Does someone have an idea on how I could fix my code instead?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to make this work using a `log` function that is defined in a shared library in `vars\log.groovy`:

```groovy
import java.io.FileWriter
import java.io.BufferedWriter
import java.io.PrintWriter

// The annotated variable will become a private field of the script class. 
@groovy.transform.Field 
PrintWriter writer = null

void call( String msg ) {
    if( ! writer ) {
        def fw = new FileWriter(file, true)
        def bw = new BufferedWriter(fw)
        writer = new PrintWriter(bw)
    }

    try {
        writer.println(msg)
        [...]
    } catch (e) {
        [...]
    }     
}
```

After all, scripts in the `vars` folder are instanciated as singleton classes, which is perfectly suited for a logger. This works even without `@NonCPS` annotation.

Usage in pipeline is as simple as:

```
log 'some message'
```